# body onmousemove event is not called when over of some elements

Tags: javascript

I do this:

```
window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
```

I want to track the mouse cursor position on the whole window, it works but when the mouse cursor is over a input textarea or iframe, then my handleMouseMove is not called, and I cannot get the actual mouse cursor position X and Y coord.

How to get mouse cursor position even if cursor is over of such elements like textare input and iframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event should be triggered even when the cursor is over `textarea` or `input`. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/482At/

However, when the cursor enters an `iframe` the event should not be triggered since technically it is outside of the current `window`. To kind of go around it you can add a `div` over the top of the `iframe`, but this also means that the user would not be able to interact with the content inside the `iframe`. Alternatively you can set its `z-index` to a negative number or set its `pointer-events` to `none`.

Comment: yes it work, maybe i will accept your answer if i do not get a better one. thanks

Comment: @ManY - I forgot to mention that, if setting the `iframe`'s `position` to `relative` won't mess up your styling, you can actually set its `z-index` to `-1` or in CSS3, you can add this line `pointer-events: none`.